# Problem with file concatenation in Python?

Tags: python, file-io, concatenation, shutil

I have 3 files `1.txt`, `2.txt`, and `3.txt` and I am trying to concatenate together the contents of these files into one output file in Python. Can anyone explain why the code below only writes the content of `1.txt` and not `2.txt` or `3.txt`? I'm sure it's something really simple, but I can't seem to figure out the problem.

```
import glob
import shutil

for my_file in glob.iglob('/Users/me/Desktop/*.txt'):
    with open('concat_file.txt', "w") as concat_file:
        shutil.copyfileobj(open(my_file, "r"), concat_file)
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you constantly overwrite the same file.

either use:

```
with open('concat_file.txt', "a")
```

or

```
with open('concat_file.txt', "w") as concat_file:
    for my_file in glob.iglob('/Users/me/Desktop/*.txt'):
        shutil.copyfileobj(open(my_file, "r"), concat_file)
```

Comment: I'm not sure it's overwriting the same file; wouldn't you end up with a copy of `3.txt` in that case?

Comment: Filenames are not necessarily stored in a directory in lexical order.

Comment: @yi_H: Oh yeah, I did know that. Haven't used it in a while. Thanks.

Comment: Ahh! Thank you, that was the problem. I appreciate the explanation as it will hopefully help me correct these oversites in the future. What confused me was the same thing that confused Tom.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that what's wrong with your code is that in every loop iteration, you are essentially adding files to themselves.

If you manually unroll the loop you will see what I mean:

```
# my_file = '1.txt'
concat_file = open(my_file)
shutil.copyfileobj(open(my_file, 'r'), concat_file)
# ...
```

I'd suggest deciding beforehand which file you want all the files to be copied to, maybe like this:

```
import glob
import shutil

output_file = open('output.txt', 'w')

for my_file in glob.iglob('/Users/me/Desktop/*.txt'):
    with open('concat_file.txt', "w") as concat_file:
        shutil.copyfileobj(open(my_file, "r"), output_file)
```

Comment: -1 `concat_file` in the original is intended to serve the purpose that `output_file` does in your sample.